# Describe all homomorphic images of the dihedral group $D_3$ of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I saw a solution for $D_4$ where they just found all the normal subgroups and found the quotient groups.  Is that sufficient here?  How do I even do that? I know that one of them is the kernel of $D_3$, which is just all of the symmetries

Comment: You can list out all subgroups. And try which among them are normal and construct quotient groups by them. Lagrange;s theorem will help in searching for subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that sufficient here?

Yes, this is the content of the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem).

> How do I even do that?

I think $D_3$ is small enough to do by hand (listing out subgroups and finding the normal ones, as suggested in the comments).

---

You did not list the elements of $D_3$ correctly if you are writing in terms of generators. (Part of it is my fault, I wrote the presentation of $D_4$ rather than $D_3$ in the comments.) Moreover, you have subgroups of size $4$, which does not divide $|D_3|=6$.

If you use the presentation $\langle r,s \mid r^3=s^2=(sr)^2=e \rangle$, then the elements can be listed as $\{e, r, r^2, s, sr, sr^2\}$.
The subgroups are $\{e\}$, $\{e, s\}$, $\{e, sr\}$, $\{e, sr^2\}$, $\{e, s, s^2\}$, and $D_3$. You can check that only $\{e\}$, $\{e, s, s^2\}$, and $D_3$ are normal.

If you want to use the notation given in your link, then the subgroups are $\{id\}$, $\{id, m_1\}$, $\{id, m_2\}$, $\{id, m_3\}$, $\{id, r_1, r_2\}$, and $D_3$. Only $\{id\}$, $\{id, r_1, r_2\}$, and $D_3$ are normal.

Comment: What would the subgroups be?  Just all of the symmetries?  How do  you even write that?

Comment: @VinnyChase You can write out all eight elements of $D_4$ in terms of the generators, i.e. a rotation $r$ and a reflection $s$ (which satisfy $r^4=e$, $s^2=e$, $(sr)^2=e$) and play around with them.

Comment: so $D_3$ = {$id, r, r^2, s, s^2, s^3$} and then the normal subgroups are: {$id, r, r^2$}, {$id, r^2, s^2, s^3$}, {$id, r^2, s, s^2$}, {$id, r, s, s^3$}, {$id, r, s^2, s^3$}, and $D_3$?  Did I miss any?  (I figured this out using the table on page 8 here http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/normal/normal.pdf)